# Is a systemd automount point mounted or not?

Tags: systemd, mount, automounting

`mountpoint` reports a mountpoint even if a `systemd` automount is not mounted:

```
% mountpoint /media/ssd
/media/ssd is a mountpoint
% mount | grep /media/ssd
systemd-1 on /media/ssd type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=35,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=13618)
```

How do I tell if an mountpoint is actually automounted or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return `0` only if `$dir` is mounted:

```
dir=/media/ssd
systemctl is-active --quiet "$(systemd-escape -p --suffix=mount "$dir")"
```

Comment: Use `--suffix=automount` to check for the presence of an automount.

Answer (score -1):

You can check in `/etc` to see what you have in the `auto.master` file and then check for all other `auto.*` files if you or anyone has created them for you.

Basically if you have autofs as stated in the last line - it is automounted.

Comment: The question is about systemd automounts, not autofs automounts.